# URLs that contains whitespace makes weird newer ending loops in Polarion ALM

Tags: apache-2.4

URLs that contains whitespace makes weird newer ending loops in Polarion ALM that is J2EE based solution that is integrated to Apache with mod_proxy / mod_ajp.

Please see the image:

[image: Weird redirection loop]

Any suggestions how to fix this?

This happen after I upgraded my Firefox to lates version. How to downgrade Firefox?

Comment: Whitespace in URL is per RFC unsafe. Please read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space

Comment: Thanks about this information. But I can't get Polarion ALM to work in latest Firefox if the is no way to allow whitespaces in URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
Type "about:config" in the address bar
Confirm that you'll be careful
Search setting dom.url.getters_decode_hash and set it to true
Done (no need to save anything, just close the config tab/window)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `%20` for whitespace substitution

Comment: Yes.. but Polarion ALM redirects link Some Page to Some%20Page looping with these both pages endless.